# Regex - Matches a string without <html> tags with all edge cases

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The string is `This is a bad string.It has <HTML> tags`. This string should not be matched as this has some HTML tags.Likewise please help me to find a good string which does not have HTML tags(attributes included).

Many resources have regex to match only the HTML tags,the regex is `/<\/?[\w\s="/.':;#-\/]+>/gi`.

Please make use of the above Regex as HINT.

Comment: What is your version, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Ive no idea , just from the start of the implementation I think

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
string === string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"")
```

It helps to have some knowledge about regexp, but let me explain one by one in my code:

`/(<([^>]+)>)/ig` so you probably know about `/ig` and about how it works like: `string.replace('.....', "")`.

Focus on `(<([^>]+)>)`, `<` start with `< >` end with `>` `([^>]+)`, the `+` means contains at least one `[^>]`. It will replace the tag name for example html, img, span and so on.

`[^>]` means any character not `'>'`

Comment: === triple equals?

Comment: yes it is, usually in javascript we use === for correctness

Comment: Thank you and @Ellatlar for you work!